# Firebase delete document, always throw PERMISION_DENIED

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I´m implementing Firebase authentication in my android project,

Using the example repo of @AlexMamo
https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle

when an user is already signed in, and is trying to Revoke Access credentials,
the next code sentence is executed

`db.collection(USERS).document(uid).delete().await()`

but it´s always throwing an error from firestore: PERMISION_DENIED

[image: firebase error]

In my firebase console I have enabled the delete option for users:

So I don´t know what´s causing this error.

[image: firebase console]

The complete code file is this: Lane 40 https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/firebasesigninwithgoogle/data/repository/ProfileRepositoryImpl.kt

Comment: Hey Olegario. As yingru shih mentioned in his answer, the problem lies in the fact that you don't have proper rules. So this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404) will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is about FireStore Security Rules.
FireStore only set basic rule to let you read and write data in default.

You can check the official document about setting your own security rules in your **Firebase Cloud Firestore Console**.

[About FireStore "Secure your data" Explanation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart)
[Create a rule that enables delete access for all users (or all authenticated users)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics?authuser=0&hl=zh)